# Linearize sum of continuous and boolean variable

Tags: linear-programming, linearization, indicator-constraints, reformulation-linearization

For maximizing the objective function $\sum_i{d_i y_i}+ A x - B \cdot \mathbb{I}_{x>0}$, how can I linearize $ A x - B \cdot \mathbb{I}_{x>0}$ term where $d_i, A$ and $B$ are positive constants and $x, y_i$ are continuous non-negative variables? Can you explain the logic of linearization? There are many other constraints involving $y_i, x$.

Comment: Minimize or maximize?

Comment: @RobPratt Maximize

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $M$ is a (small) upper bound on $x$, introduce a binary variable $z$ and big-M constraint $x \le M z$. The idea is that $x>0$ implies $z=1$. Now use $B z$ in the objective.

Comment: But x=0 doesn’t imply z=0. Is it handled by requirement of maximization of the objective?

Comment: Yes, the objective will naturally drive that.